# 'Active' and 'inactive' lambda terms and Church.

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations, lambda-calculus

In the historic survey on lambda calculus and combinators *'History of lambda-calculus and combinatory logic'* by Cardone and Hindley, we read:

> (Church’s name is often associated with the λI-calculus, the version
>   of λ-calculus in which λx.M is only counted as a term when x occurs
>   free in M. But he did not limit himself so strictly to this version as
>   is often thought. In 1932 and ’33 he allowed non-λI-terms λx.M to
>   exist but not to be “active”, i.e. he did not allow a term (λx.M)N to
>   be contracted when x did not occur free in M, see [Church, 1932, pp.
>   352, 355]. In his 1940 paper on type theory, where consistency would
>   have been less in doubt, although probably not yet actually proved, he
>   was happy for non-λI-terms to be active [Church, 1940, pp. 57, 60].
>   Only in his 1941 book did he forbid their very existence [Church,
>   1941, p. 8].)

Can anyone shed light on why such terms being allowed or not, or being considered 'active' or not is an important issue?

Comment: From a Curry-Howard perspective, that restriction corresponds to working in [relevance logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic). If you want to do $\beta$-expansion, that restriction avoids the awkwardness that *any* term $M$ can be $\beta$-expanded to $(\lambda x.M)N$ where $x$ is not free in $M$ and $N$ can be any term whatsoever. With the restriction, $N$ will always be a subterm of $M$. I'm not sure what was motivating this for him though.

Comment: Less awkwardness alone seems not to be a big enough reason for the author adding such a paragraph wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I think there is nothing "deep" in this issue. Modern treatments (see e.g.Hendrik Pieter Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZdydJZVue50C), Elsevier (rev ed 1984), page 22), define the syntax as follows: "The set of $\lambda$-terms $\Lambda$ is defined inductively as follows: (i) $x \in \Lambda$; (ii) $M \in \Lambda \Rightarrow (\lambda x M) \in \Lambda$;..."

Comment: But the underlying intuition (see page 6) is: "Let $t (\equiv t(x))$ be an expression *possibly* [emphasis added] containing $x$. Then $\lambda x . t(x)$ is the function $f$ that assigns to the argument $a$ the value $t(a)$. That is: $(\beta) \ \ (\lambda x . t(x)) a = t(a)$." The definition is general but clearly, if the function $f$ has no argument-place (i.e. has no free occurrences of $x$) the assignment to $a$ as argument has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the $\lambda I$ calculus is intimately related to [relevance logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic). As you can see from that Wikipedia page, this was a topic that interested Alonzo Church. However, this connection is less strong in an untyped context.

The second part of my comment is meant to be suggestive of meta-theoretical properties $\lambda I$ has that the normal $\lambda$ calculus does not. Since $\lambda I$ is still Turing-complete (as we'd say nowadays), these simpler meta-logical properties are convenient. [This answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16517/37134) briefly discusses some of those meta-theoretic properties referencing a short discussion of $\lambda I$ in Barendregt's "The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics".

If we drop the requirement that $x$ is free in $M$ in $\lambda x.\!M$ *but* we compensate by making $(\lambda x.\!M)N$ not reducible (if $M$ and $N$ are irreducible), then it becomes a normal form, and we maintain at least some of the meta-theoretical properties while loosening the syntax a bit. In particular, this change keeps the property, discussed in the aforementioned answer, that if a term $T$ has a normal form, then so do all its subterms. Note that this is not true in the $\lambda$ calculus. For example, with the term $(\lambda x.\!\lambda y.\!y)((\lambda w.\!ww)(\lambda w.\!ww))$ which has the normal form $\lambda y.\!y$ though $(\lambda w.\!ww)(\lambda w.\!ww)$ has no normal form. If we disallow the $\beta$-reduction involving $x$, then the term has no normal form.